# inApp purchase PENDING in Purchase history

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

In my application when a user pay with in-app purchase transaction is getting completed but when the user checks the purchase history it shows "Pending" status. when I validate the purchase receipt with apple am gtting status 21007 with sandbox user. Can anybody help me how to check the "pending" status scenario with apple? In receipt validation.

Comment: After payment success than validate your purchase receipt and check status date etc. For Sandbox user duration you can check  https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev7e89e149d

Comment: The status code 21007 stands for => This receipt is from the test environment, but it was sent to the production environment for verification. Send it to the test environment instead.

Comment: Probably your URL for requesting the receipt validation was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Please use below **URL** to verify receipt validation.

The error code you are getting **21007** stands for **==>** This receipt is from the test environment, but it was sent to the production environment for verification. Send it to the test environment instead

```
guard let appStoreReceiptURL = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL, let appStoreReceiptData = try? Data(contentsOf: appStoreReceiptURL), let verifyReceipt = URL(string: "https://\((appStoreReceiptURL.lastPathComponent == "sandboxReceipt" ? "sandbox" : "buy")).itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt") else {


            return
        }
```

Comment: Your welcome @Graycodder, Happy to know that its work for you. Please accept the answer and upvote it. So other developers who are facing this problem can have idea about this.